# Finding a vector representation for a data where we only know the inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, applied-mathematics

I am an engineer working on speech signal processing and I have a problem that I have encountered while trying to model speech signals. The mathematical formulation is not entirely pure and I try to explain this verbatim wherever I find difficult to put in the form of equations or proper mathematical abstraction.

I have a random variable $R$ which takes values from an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. The exact probability distribution of $R$ is unknown, but known to be supported on an  open ball. There is a large collection $S$ of size $N$, of the outcomes of the random variable $R$, but don't have access to them. All i have access to, is the inner products between each one of them. I mean I only know $\langle \phi_i,\phi_j \rangle$ $\forall i,j \in \{1,2,3...N\}$ where $\phi_i \in S$. Now I need to find a vector representation, that is a map $\alpha : S\to\mathbb{R}^d$, such that the correlation coefficient $\rho$ of the data  $(\langle \phi_i,\phi_j \rangle,\langle \alpha(\phi_i),\alpha(\phi_j) \rangle)$ is maximum. I 'd like to know any algorithm to do this. Right now, the choice of $d$ can be taken as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking it doesn't make much sense to talk about defining a function on $S$ when you've explicitly said you don't know any of the elements of $S$.  I'll assume rather that you have a sequence $\phi_1,\ldots, \phi_N$ of vectors which you don't know, but whose inner products you do know, such that you would like to find a sequence $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_N$ of vectors of length $d$ which have the same inner products.  That is, I'll talk about $\alpha_i$ instead of $\alpha(\phi_i)$.

Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ (here I'm assuming you're working over the reals, but the situation works out the same for complex coefficients) be the "Gram matrix" defined by $M_{ij} = \langle\phi_i,\phi_j\rangle$.  For any column vector $x$, $x^TMx = \lVert\sum_k x_k\phi_k\rVert^2\geq 0$, so $M$ is positive semidefinite.  Therefore there exists a "square root" $F\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, a matrix which satisfies $M = F^T F$.

Define $\alpha_i$ to be column number $i$ of $F$.  Then $\langle\phi_i,\phi_j\rangle = \langle\alpha_i,\alpha_j\rangle$ holds exactly, so the correlation is $1$.  But we have used the relatively large $d = N$.  If you only care about the inner products being approximately equal, you can apply the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma and randomly project the $\alpha(\phi_i)$ to get as good an approximate version as you'd like with $d = O(\log n)$.

Do you really care about maximizing the given correlation of those two inner products, or is making them nearly equal good enough?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply and effort for the answer. I got your point and the technical pit fall in my question. As you might be aware of the usual problem setup in a statistical machine learning, my usual intention is to use a large collection of examples and try to learn something which we can use over examples coming in the future. So my intention is to learn from a large collection of size $N$, and then use what ever learnt from it over the future examples. So my mistake is stating $\alpha : S \to \mathbb{R}^d$. If this is the case, then I am not learning anything!...

Comment: (continued).... My main intention is to learn and estimate the hypothetical map $\alpha_h : H \to \mathbb{R}^d$, where the $H$ is the Hilbert space associated with the random variable $R$. I intended to use a large collection $S$ of size $N$, for the purpose of estimating/learning the map $\alpha_h: H \to \mathbb{R}^d$.  I am interested to maximize correlation coefficient over the training set $S$.

Comment: With your due permission I would like to mend my question as per this, otherwise the point you have raised would make my question dumb.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: At first I thought $\alpha_h$ was what you were after, but how could you say anything about that when you don't know anything about the $\phi_i$ themselves, just their inner products?  That is to say, how do you go about defining a function on $H$ with properties you want when you don't have any elements of $H$ or functions on $H$ about which you know something?  In what form would you hope to express $\alpha_h$?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: If you clarify your question to address this, I'm happy to delete this answer and comment thread.

Comment: I don't intend to get an expression for $\alpha_h$. Clearly boiling down, apart from $S$, suppose the random variable has emitted $\phi_{test} \in H$, but I dont know $\phi_{test}$, all I know are $\langle \phi_{test},\phi_i\rangle$, $i = 1,2,3..N$, and ofcourse the already existing  gram matrix $M_{ij}$, and using this data I want an algorithm to find (the estimate) $\alpha_h(\phi_{test})$. I want this algorithm to use only the knowledge of gram matrix $M_{ij}$ and ofcourse $\langle  \phi_{test},\phi_i\rangle$, $i = 1,2,3..N$. I wish to maximize correlation coefficient $\rho$.

Comment: Well, $M$ and this new data contain enough information to use Gram-Schmidt to determine coefficients $\lambda_i$ of the orthogonal projection $\sum_i \lambda_i \phi_i$ of $\phi_{test}$ onto the span of $S$, right?  Then you can give your estimate as $\alpha_h(\phi_{test}) = \sum_i \lambda_i \alpha_h(\phi_i)$.  I'm not immediately sure if this maximizes the correlation, but at least it should give a good approximation when you have a lot of samples.  Is it really important that your error metric be precisely maximizing the correlation, or do you just want to approximate the inner products well?

Comment: Wow it really works with the data I have! My concern now is the dimensionality reduction, making $d << N$ or $d = O(logN)$. Please let me know if there is any algorithm for Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma that you have mentioned. I hope I can reduce $d$ in my case. Again Thanks a lot for the help. I wish I had enough rep to upvote.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: You're welcome.  Johnson-Lindenstrauss says that for appropriate size $d$ a scaled version of a projection onto a random subspace will approximately preserve the distances, hence the inner products, with high probability.  So the standard thing to do is pick a $d$ and pick $d$ many random vectors, project onto these vectors, inflate things because on average projecting reduces norm, and see what you get.  Theoretically you may have to repeat this a few times for it to work.  If it still doesn't, your $d$ is probably too small.

Comment: Would you consider adding your important comments to your answer, assuming that you being generous on understanding my intention of estimating $\alpha_h$ as opposed to what I incorrectly stated in my question. I think this will make the Q&A complete and useful for any reader.

Comment: Also I stick with error being small than the correlation